# Web Service: 403 Forbidden error

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to access some data from a service into my `windows service`.
This is the code in one of the threads:

```
HttpWebRequest webrequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url + "/data.json?auth_token=" + authenticationToken);
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
               ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

webrequest.Method = "GET";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/jsonp";

HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse) webrequest.GetResponse();
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

result = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

It was working properly before. But since few days, it is giving error: 
`The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`

EDIT:

If I try the request through browser, I get the response properly, but not through windowa service!

Comment: The code "403 FORBIDDEN" is fairly self-explanatory; for some reason it doesn't think you're allowed to do that. Do you have any control over the server, or is it a third party?

Comment: Were is your web service running?  Have you changed your windows password recently and not updated the pwd details in IIS?

Comment: @anaximander, it's third party.

Comment: @KOL, no. Everything is at it is.

Answer (score 0):

> It was working properly before. But since few days, it is giving error

First thing to check: has the certificate expired?

Comment: It is working when I hit the URL through browser. Are there any other factors required when calling through windows service?